# How can a string array store arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I know that the array declaration below is correct:

```
String[][] arrayNew={{"teresa","human","jennifer"},{"18","20"},{"nothing"}};
```

I understand that `String` and `array` are two different object types in java.So how come the `string array arrayNew` is successfully storing three different arrays in it.
An `int` array can not store `doubles`but how come a `string array` is able to store `arrays`?

Comment: How come arrayNew is a string array? its an array of an array of string man.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Got it now.I was confused probably.

Comment: Okay.It was actually a problem with the basics.My teacher had asked us to consider a 2D array as a matrix and this made it confusing.But now it's pretty clear.

Comment: great to here u got it :)

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a way which invalidates posted answers. If you have additional question ask them in new post.

Comment: @Pshemo So sorry about it.It was just a small doubt and so I thought all related things could be put into one question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just creating a 2D array (An array of String array).

On this particular case, you created a jagged array.

You could do the same for int array as well:

```
int[][] array = {{1,2,3}, {4,5}, {6}};
```

**Multidimensional arrays** are **array of arrays:**

```
String[] arrayA;       //Array of Strings
String[][] arrayB;     //Array of (Array of Strings)
String[][][] arrayC;   //Array of (Array of (Array of Strings))
String[][][][] arrayD; //Array of (Array of (Array of (Array of Strings)))
```

Comment: I found this pretty useful.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MathewsMathai You are welcome, but I don't know why people somehow down voted it.

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile, and thus makes things more confusing than helpful: you can NOT store arrays of ints in an int[], as your code suggests.

Comment: @JBNizet Ah yes, I missed out the bracket. Now it is compliable.

Comment: @MathewsMathai I was reading it, but it was gone. Maybe you want to start a fresh question? I will help you take a look at it.

Comment: @user3437460   `String[][] array24=new String[2][2];`...I have declared this array and has given it some size.Does this array already contain `empty arrays` in it?...This was the doubt.It was related and so I thought I could put it one place.

Comment: @MathewsMathai No problem. Actually there are 2 parts in `String[][] array24=new String[2][2]`. The first part being `String[][] array24;` can be left alone by itself and remain compilable. It means creating a variable for an array of String array. No arrays created at this point. The 2nd part `new String[2][2]` where you see the `new` keyword means an object (in this case, your array) is created. So with both parts combined, you did create a 2D string array which is empty (the string elements are empty). But the array exist.

Comment: @user3437460 I am talking about the inner arrays.`array24` consists of arrays of type string..right??...So are those inner arrays also created at the same time when the main array is created?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99055/discussion-between-user3437460-and-mathews-mathai).

Answer (score 4):

You can think of `Type[]` as one-dimensional array which can store elements of described `Type`. So `Type[]` array can look like `{Type0, Type1, Type2}`.

Now lets say that we want to create array which can store 1D arrays. How should we declare it? Our `Type` will need to be replaced with `String[]` which will give us

```
String[][] arrayNew
^^^^^^^^
type of elements which can be stored directly in `arrayNew`
```

So since `Type` is `String[]`, it means that `arrayNew` is not *String array*, but *array of String arrays*

```
{    [0]        [1]        [2]   }
      ↓          ↓          ↓    
  String[],  String[],  String[]
  //each of these 1D array can store its own elements.
```

Comment: That means 2D arrays and above can only store arrays(of the same type)...am I right?

Comment: Yes, 2D arrays like `arrayNew` can store only 1D String arrays, and these 1D arrays can store Strings.

Comment: I have edited the above question to ask one more doubt which emerged from the previous one.Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 2):

`arrayNew` is not a string array (`String[]`) it's an array of arrays of strings (`String[][]`). As such, each of its elements is an array of strings - `{"teresa","human","jennifer"}` (an array of strings with three elements) , `{"18","20"}` (an array of strings with two elements) and `{"nothing"}` (an array of strings with a single element).

Answer (score 2):

Since it's declared as `String[][]` with two `[]` this means it's a two-dimensional array.
In other words:
`String` - can contain only one string
`String[]` - can contain an array of strings (multiple strings)
`String[][]` - can contain an array of arrays of strings (multiple arrays of multiple strings)
... and so on

Answer (score 1):

`arrayNew` is a reference to an 2d array of type `String` and all the elements are also of `string` type, so it compiles.

ex: `String[] arr  = {"abc","xyz"};`, `arr` is referring to an array of type `String` ,`arr` is not the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the string array can hold multiple arrays since its a Two Dimensional Array. [Here](https://www.processing.org/tutorials/2darray/) is a documentation about it.

Integers can also do that as the following:

```
int[][] myArray = {  {0, 1, 2, 3},
                     {3, 2, 1, 0},
                     {3, 5, 6, 1},
                     {3, 8, 3, 4}  };
```

Answer (score 1):

`String[]` is an array of Strings.

`Foo[]` is an array of Foos.

`Bar[]` is an array of Bars.

So, `String[][]` is an array of String[]s. I.e. an array of arrays of Strings. That's why it can store arrays of Strings.

Comment: That means 2D arrays and above can only store arrays(of the same type)...am I right?

Comment: I would think in terms of 2D or 3D arrays. Just in terms of arrays (which is the reality, BTW). String[][] is an array of String[], which can thus store String[] instances. Just like Banana[] is an array of Bananas that can store Banana instances. And Foo[][][] is an array of Fo[][] that can store Fo[][] instances.

Comment: What I meant is *I would NOT think in terms of 2D or 3D arrays*.