# How to print out 2d array with undefined indexes

Tags: java, arrays

In a 1d array I code just do this.

```
int n=//something to input number here.
String s[]=new String [n];
for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){ System.out.println(s[i]); }
//Or using foreach but im really focusing on getting the length of the array
```

but in a 2d array i dont know if theres like a .length() method.

Comment: 2d array is an array of arrays. `length` is a property that every array has, so yes.. there is (and it's not a method).

Comment: use  the `length` of outer array in outer loop and then use `length` of inner arrays in a inner loop and then print individual elements

Comment: `Arrays.deepToString(your2dArray)`give this a try.

Comment: @Maroun I know, but with a 2d array what does it return? example like 
`String[][]s={{"a","b"},{"c","d"}}; //s.length` does it return 2,2 or what?

Comment: @Alpha give it a try. It returns the number of elements in the array, which happens to be an array of arrays. It contains 2 things (arrays), so it returns 2.

Comment: In schools, they explain it as 2D and multi-dimensional arrays but there is no such thing called 2D arrays. I had a similar problem with understanding what it really is. Hope this helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482488/how-can-a-string-array-store-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use length on each array.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < array[i].length : j++) {
        // doStuff with array[i][j]
    }
}
```

---

Now, if you just need to print the array to check the values you can use the following method

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

It prints the array, and the arrays within it.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 2D arrays are jagged arrays, meaning arrays of arrays. The array itself has `length` and each element of it (itself an array) also has `length`. You just use nested loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
    }
}
```